# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token;

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

I am trying to inject `Facebook pixel` code using `jQuery`.

I couldn't find a direct way of doing it and hence following the below approach. However, I am getting an syntax error.

```
var t = "!function (f, b, e, v, n, t, s) { if (f.fbq) return; n = f.fbq = function () {n.callMethod ? n.callMethod.apply(n, arguments) : n.queue.push(arguments)}; if (!f._fbq) f._fbq = n;n.push = n; n.loaded = !0; n.version = '2.0' ; n.queue = []; t = b.createElement(e); t.async = !0;t.src = v; s = b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(t, s)}(window,document, ; n.queue = []; t = b.createElement(e); t.async = !0;t.src = v; s = b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(t, s)}(window,document, 'script','https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');fbq('init', '274827424829492');fbq('track', 'SomePage');";

$('<script>').attr('type', 'text/javascript').text(t).appendTo('head');
```

I am getting an error on `var t = '.......';`

Comment: Provide the error as well.

Comment: @theblindprophet, the error is on the long string `t`

Comment: I realize that, just copy and past the error itself. It'll normally tell you where the syntax is invalid.'

Comment: @theblindprophet, it shows the red twigley on the whole statement.

Comment: Where from do you get that error - directly from the code as shown above, or from within the script element that is dynamically created?

Comment: Why are you not just appending a script directly?

Answer (score 0):

The mistake was at the concatenated string. Below is the correct string.

```
var t = "!function (f, b, e, v, n, t, s) { if (f.fbq) return; n = f.fbq = function () {n.callMethod ? n.callMethod.apply(n, arguments) : n.queue.push(arguments)}; if (!f._fbq) f._fbq = n;n.push = n; n.loaded = !0; n.version = '2.0'; n.queue = []; t = b.createElement(e); t.async = !0;t.src = v; s = b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(t, s)}(window,document, 'script','https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');fbq('init', '3535353535355');fbq('track', 'SomePage');";
```